# Is there a way have a value not updated by an interval once the user has updated it in an angular template?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a chunk of html that is updated periodically from the controller.  Here is the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
    <td>{{product.description}}</td>
    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
    <td><input  value="{{product.price}}"/></td>
</tr>
```

If a user changes the value though, I don't want it to be updated by the interval with the old data. Is there a way to only have it update `product.price` the first time?

Here is the relevant controller code:

```
$interval(function(){
     DappStore.getProducts()
         .then(function(data){
           $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.products = data;
         });
     },1000);
},1000);
```

Comment: Subject and question are completely different. Not really clear what you are asking. *"update first time"* ... first time what...page loads? edits made? What about the *"blank"* mentioned in subject?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  The values in the template are being filled by an interval poll in the controller.  I was updating $scope.products in the interval but this was causing product.price to be overwritten in the template if a user had updated it.

Comment: Suggest you update question then because that is not a trivial change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-Time-Binding is the Keyword.

> One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value.

All you have to do is to change your code like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in ::products"> <!--HERE ARE THE CHANGE "::"-->
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
    <td>{{product.description}}</td>
    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
    <td><input  value="{{product.price}}"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The problem is that I am polling another service so I actually need to pull in new records without disturbing the old ones. I ended up finding a solution, though it is ugly as sin.

Comment: Maybe you could use "track by product.id" and then add the bind-once-syntax to the <td> elements

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use one-way data binding instead of two-way data binding.

Simply use `{{::product.name}}` instead of `{{name}}`

For more info:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

With this in the controller polling interval, only the newer values are created but anything in the page won't be touched.

```
$interval(function(){
  DappStore.getProducts()
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        var products_length;
        if(typeof $scope.products == 'undefined'){
          products_length = 0;
          $scope.products = [];
        } else {
          products_length = $scope.products.length;
        }

        for(var i = products_length; i < data.length; i++){
          $scope.products[i] = data[i];
        }
      });
    });
},1000);
```